# Problem in retrieving the apex code coverage from tooling api

Tags: apex, code-coverage, tooling-api

```
public class Cover{
    private static List<codecov> coverlist = new List<codecov>();
    private static List<Jsondat> jd = new List<Jsondat>(); 
    public class Jsondat
    {
        public String ApexClassOrTriggerId; 
        public Integer NumLinesCovered; 
        public Integer NumLinesUncovered;
    }
    public class codecov
    {
        public String ApexClassName; 
        public Integer NumLinesCovered; 
        public Integer NumLinesUncovered;
    }
    public void basicAuthCallout()
    {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseURL().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v37.0/tooling/query/?q=Select+ApexClassorTriggerId,NumLinesCovered,NumLinesUncovered+from+ApexCodeCoverageAggregate');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);      
        jd = (List<Jsondat>) System.JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(),Jsondat.class); 
        for(Jsondat covList : jd)
        {
            codecov coList = new codecov();
            coList.ApexClassName=CovList.ApexClassorTriggerId;
            coList.NumLinesCovered=CovList.NumLinesCovered;
            coList.NumLinesUncovered=CovList.NumLinesUncovered;
            coverlist.add(coList);
        }
        sendEmail(createMailBody(coverlist));
    }
    public static void sendEmail(String body){
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Admin');
        mail.setSubject('Coverage Status');
        String mailBody = body; 
        mail.setHtmlBody(mailBody);
        List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();  
        sendTo.add('mymailid');\\I used my mail id;
        mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);            
        mails.add(mail);
        Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
    }   
    public static String createMailBody(List<codecov> results){
        String mailBody = '<html><body>';
        mailBody = mailBody + '<b>Code Coverage Status as of '+ System.now() + '</b><br/><br/>';
        mailBody = mailBody + '<table style="width:100%" border="1">';
        mailBody = mailBody + '<tr>'+
            '<td bgcolor="Blue"><b><font color="white">Class Name</font></b></td>'+
            '<td bgcolor="Blue"><b><font color="white">NumLinesCovered</font></b></td>'+
            '<td bgcolor="Blue"><b><font color="white">NumLinesUncovered</font></b></td>'+
            '</tr>';
        for(codecov result : results){
            mailBody = mailBody + '<tr>';
            mailBody = mailBody + '<td>' + result.ApexClassName+ '</td>';
            mailBody = mailBody + '<td>' + result.NumLinesCovered + '</td>';
            mailBody = mailBody + '<td>' + result.NumLinesUncovered+ '</td>';
            mailBody = mailBody + '</tr>';
        }
        mailBody = mailBody + '</table>';
        mailBody = mailBody + '</body></html>';
        return mailBody;
    }
}
```

I am not getting the result to my mail.kindly help me on this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you print your response:

```
system.debug('res.getBody(): '+res.getBody());
```

You will see next structure:

```
{
    "size": 2,
    "totalSize": 2,
    "done": true,
    "queryLocator": null,
    "entityTypeName": "ApexCodeCoverageAggregate",
    "records": [{
        "attributes": {
            "type": "ApexCodeCoverageAggregate",
            "url": "/services/data/v37.0/tooling/sobjects/ApexCodeCoverageAggregate/71536000001TkKmAAK"
        },
        "ApexClassOrTriggerId": "01q36000000JeNVAA0",
        "NumLinesCovered": 0,
        "NumLinesUncovered": 6
    }, {
        "attributes": {
            "type": "ApexCodeCoverageAggregate",
            "url": "/services/data/v37.0/tooling/sobjects/ApexCodeCoverageAggregate/71536000000ND6tAAG"
        },
        "ApexClassOrTriggerId": "01q360000004jhoAAA",
        "NumLinesCovered": 0,
        "NumLinesUncovered": 12
    }]
}
```

Result you're looking for is stored in array records, that's why json.deserialize throws error.
All you need is to add class that has an array of Jsondat:

```
public class CoverageWrapper{
    list<Jsondat> records;
}
```

And replace your json deserialization with:

```
CoverageWrapper acca = (CoverageWrapper)System.JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(),CoverageWrapper.class); 

for(Jsondat covList : acca.records) {
```

Comment: Shouldn't you deserialize to `List<ApexCodeCoverageAggregate>.class`?

Comment: It's only accessible within tooling Api.

Comment: Ah, I see what's going on. Guess I just got tripped up on the name of your recommended class. Perhaps something along the lines of `QueryData` or `CodeCoverageData` or something that sounds less like the standard stuff would be less confusing?

Comment: You right, I picked bad name, one day back I didn't even know that such class ApexCodeCoverageAggregate exists.

Comment: Nice, I'd +1 again if I could. It'd be nice if you could just use a scheduled report to achieve the same underlying functionality. Ah well.

Comment: It is not triggering email.even i change it.For this line i am not getting any json output:system.debug('res.getBody(): '+res.getBody());.Note: I am running the code in anonymous block

Comment: Do you call it from dev console, execute anonymous? or somehow externally. I call Cover cr = new cover();
cr.basicAuthCallout(); from dev console. If you provide my changes, it should work, You migth miss something. Since you are looking into logs, do you see any exception. You also can have invalid sessionID for this user, or access or smth. Add try catch block and store result in custom object.